# Can I change the background color of child row on expandable list view in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have created expandable list view.I want to that I have changed the background color of child row on click of particular child row.I have done,but I am facing new problem that whenever I do  expand/collapse of expandable list view then the position of background color is change.I want to that background color child row is not changed on expand /collapse expandable list view.Please suggest me how to handle this problem.

Comment: follow this link , it's may help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584229/how-to-change-text-color-in-simpleexpandablelistadapter/14584887#14584887

Answer (score 0):

i think you have used convertview==null comparision in getChildView(), while expanding list to show child item, if child already created previous child view will be used.

```
getChildView()
{
    ......
    ......
    if(pos == 1)
      convertview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    else
      convertview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```